# thoughts on separated geometry

Tags: modeling, shaders

this is the initial mesh
[image]

but the problem is that the ring i added creates this undesired effet

[image]

i found a solution that is leaving the mesh separated
[image]

[image]

the only other solution I can think of would require increasing the number of rings, but i'm trying to keep it lowpoly. What are your thoughts on this solution i've found? could it cause some problem later down the line?

Comment: This is a very general question and not really suited for stack exchange.  Can it create problems?  Sure.  If you're trying for hyperrealism, then the lack of attachment will show. Will it create problems?  Depends on how you intend to use the object.  If you're only going to render static images, then your solution would work fine, for example, and a lot of modelers solve problems in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 2):

The line is being caused by a "crease" which is the result of 2 edges being too close together on a curved surface. Although the inner edge is necessary for the geometry of the "top part", it is interfering with your mesh where the geometry is not needed.

One thing you could do is grab a section of the inner edge in the middle of each "gap" and edge slide (<kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) it so it pulls the second edge away from the first where they don't need to be close together. There may still be some artifacts in the corners though (circled in yellow), and if this ends up looking too incorrect, you may be best going with 2 separate pieces.

[image]